# How to break image path to return only image name without extension

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

I have an image URL `"https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-Free-Images-Background-PC-PIC-WPD006550.jpg"`

I want to remove base path(`https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/`) and file extension(`.jpg`) and **it should be return** `wallpaper.wiki-Free-Images-Background-PC-PIC-WPD006550`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is not market place where you put your request and people accept it for money, please consider making effort and if you reach a dead end, we'll be here to help.

Comment: @ThijsKramer, I tried this `.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split(".")[0]` , but it returns only "wallpaper"

Comment: Can you share the regex or code you tried?

Comment: Try `.split('/').pop().slice(0,-4);` -4 means 4 chars from the back that's if the extensions is 3 letters long.

Comment: Thanks @ZohirSalak, That's what I want..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex to extract filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092244/regex-to-extract-filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex and capture group 1's content which will pick only the filename in the url excluding the extension,

```
https?:\/\/.*\/([\w.-]+)\.\w+
```

Explanation:

```
https?:\/\/.*/ --> captures the url from start and stops at last occurrence of /
([\w.-]+) --> captures the filename
\.\w+ --> captures the dot and extension
```

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/eralSI/1

Here is a javascript code for achieving same,

```js
var myString = "https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-Free-Images-Background-PC-PIC-WPD006550.jpg";
var myRegexp = /https?:\/\/.*\/([\w.-]+)\.\w+/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```